# Rails Migration - Spree Commmerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I want to add featured and latest products to my homepage, I am replicating the spree_fancy gem method and using the below migration to add taxons but not show the tags in the side bar but I am unsure what this part of the migrataion is doing -

```
products = Spree::Product.all

if products[6] 
  products[0..6].each do |product|
    product.taxons << slider
  end
end

if products[16]
  products[4..16].each do |product|
    product.taxons << featured
  end

  products[0..12].each do |product|
    product.taxons << latest
  end
```

Here is the full migation

```
class AddSliderTaxonsAndApplyThem < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
  tags      = Spree::Taxonomy.create(:name => 'Tags')
  slider    = Spree::Taxon.create({:taxonomy_id => tags.id, :name => 'Slider'})
  featured  = Spree::Taxon.create({:taxonomy_id => tags.id, :name => 'Featured'})
  latest    = Spree::Taxon.create({:taxonomy_id => tags.id, :name => 'Latest'})

  products = Spree::Product.all

  if products[6] 
    products[0..6].each do |product|
      product.taxons << slider
    end
  end

  if products[16]
    products[4..16].each do |product|
      product.taxons << featured
    end

    products[0..12].each do |product|
      product.taxons << latest
    end
  end
  end

  def down
    Spree::Taxonomy.where(:name => 'Tags').first.destroy()
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan,

That part of the migration is simply assigning products to each taxon. When you're actually using it, you don't need that, as you'll be picking and choosing what products to put in each category.

Comment: I have an issue with this migration. At present it doesn't seem to run the def down part and therefore 'Tags' is still in the DB and visible on the screen which I don't want(I only want the Taxons) so if I boot up the console and manually run the destroy command on the Taxonomy it removes the 'Latest' Taxonn from the DB, any ideas?